# Accessing Mapped Type where Values Cannot be Intersected, Handler Pattern

Tags: typescript, dependent-type, type-theory

I'm not sure if the title accurately describes my issue, but here is the code I'm working with:

```
const EnumValues = ["a", "b", "c"] as const;
type Enum = typeof EnumValues[number];

type Data = {
    a: boolean,
    b: number,
    c: string,
}

type Handlers = {
  a: (datum: Data["a"]) => void,
  b: (datum: Data["b"]) => void,
  c: (datum: Data["c"]) => void,
}

type Session = {[E in Enum]: Data[E]}

const data: Data = {a: false, b: 0, c: ""}
const handlers: Handlers = {a: (_) => {}, b: (_) => {}, c: (_) => {}}

for (const e of EnumValues) {
    // this line results in an error because `handlers[e]` has type `never`.
    // this is because (I think) that the functions in `Handlers[Enum]` are
    // being intersected instead of being predicated on `e`.
    handlers[e](e)
}
```

I can understand *why* the issue is occurring given that typescript is resolving `handlers[e]` to have type `never` since it's intersecting all of `Handlers[Enum]`.

While the code above is a simplistic example, the functions inside of `handlers` do in fact depend on the types of `Data[e]` in my "real world" code.

I'm not sure if some dependent or existential typing is necessary here, but is this possible at all in a type-safe manner in Typescript?

Comment: Typescript won't be able to track the relation between `handlers[e]` and `e`. You will need to use a type assertion.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to make this work:

```
type Handlers<T> = {[K in keyof T]: (datum: T[K]) => void}

function getHandler<S, T extends keyof S>(h: Handlers<S>, e: T): (datum: S[T]) => void { 
  return h[e]
}

const EnumValues = ["a", "b", "c"] as const;
type Enum = typeof EnumValues[number];

type Data = {
    a: boolean,
    b: number,
    c: string,
}

const data: Data = {a: false, b: 0, c: ""}
const handlers: Handlers<Data> = {a: (_) => {}, b: (_) => {}, c: (_) => {}}

for (const e of EnumValues) {
    getHandler(handlers, e)(data[e])
}
```

The trick is to not let Typescript know what the keys are to `handlers`, because then it will expand the type of `handlers[e]` to a union, and it looses track of which key you used to look up the handler. To do this I used a generic type (instead of the specific `Data`) in a helper function.